# Jquery: get the ids of multiple file elements in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have an input field for multiple file uploads. When i upload multiple files the id is set different each time the file gets posted which is fine by the way. Now what i want is to get the ids of all the files thats being uploaded at once in an array.

P.S: I am integrating a jquery multiple file upload in my django app.

My js code:

```
console.log(result['id']);
```

The above code will output the id of the respective files being uploaded in the console.

django views:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save()
    files = [serialize(self.object)]
    data = {'files': files, 'id' : self.object.id }
```

I hope I'm clear enough to explain my problem.

Comment: Are you looking for JavaScript code, or Python?

Comment: Thanks @dave for the reply. I acutally am looking for a javascript code.

Comment: a file input can only have a single ID, even with the multiple attribute set.

Comment: Yes @dandavis. But the reference here are the files.. I have multiple ids set for multiple files being uploaded. And Now, I only want these files' id in array.

Comment: i am confused as to what ID you're referring to; files from html input's got have IDs, just names and indexes...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your exact plugin works, but I would try the following, it should give you an array of all the `id`s of the file `inputs` on your page:

```
$('input[type="file"]').toArray().map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
);
```

Here's a runnable sample:

```js
var ids = $('input[type="file"]').toArray().map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
});
alert(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload1" />
<input type="file" id="fileUpload2" />
<input type="file" id="fileUpload3" />
```

Comment: It didnt work. It alerts one pop-up for each files being uploaded.

Comment: Which file upload plugin are you using specifically?

Comment: I am using django-jquery-file-upload by sebastian Tschan